# Asignar código de gráfico spineplot a una variable plot_1

Tags: r

Dispongo de un código que contiene una función que imprime un tipo particular de gráficos spineplot.

```
library("RColorBrewer")
print.perc <- function(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct="%", min=0.1, cex=0.8) {
  nx <- nrow(tbl)
  off <- 0.02
  xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(margin.table(tbl, 1)) + off))
  posx <- (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2
  ptbl <- prop.table(tbl,1)
  lbl <- ifelse(ptbl[k,] >= min,
                paste(format(round(100*ptbl[k,], ndigits), nsmall=ndigits), str.pct, "\n",colnames(tbl), sep=""),
                "")
  text(posx[k], cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2, lbl, cex=cex)
}
paleta <- brewer.pal(nlevels(y),"RdYlBu")
tbl <- spineplot(y ~ as.factor(x),
                 col=paleta, 
                 xlab = "x", 
                 ylab ="y", 
                 yaxlabels = "", 
                 main= "Round 1") 

for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2)
```

Me gustaría aprender a asignar este tipo de código a una variable denominada, por ejemplo, "plot_1", de tal manera que ejecutando solo "plot_1" aparezca el gráfico. De esta manera podré utilizar grid.arrange para imprimir multigráficos.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te habrás dado cuenta, en las funciones base de graficación, los plots se implementan como un "side effect",  es decir, la función no retorna el gráfico sino que simplemente lo dibuja. "Capturar" el `plot` para usarlo después es posible, pero no necesariamente te va a funcionar de la forma en que trabaja `ggplot` si es lo que estás buscando hacer.

Veamos que opciones tienes (Fuente: [Save a plot in an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29583849/6836377)):

#### Usar [`recordPlot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/recordplot.html)

Con esto obtenemos un objeto del tipo `recordedplot` que podremos invocar en cualquier momento y reproducirá el `plot` original.

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2),
                    labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),
                   levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                   labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))

spineplot(improved ~ treatment)
p1 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

spineplot(treatment ~ improved)
p2 <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

p1
p2
```

#### Usar una aproximación funcional

Acá lo que hacemos en realidad en definir funciones para cada variante del gráfico. El objeto final será una función del mismo tipo que la original y cada vez que se requiera se ejecutará nuevamente, obviamente la sintaxis cambia por que se trata de una función, lo bueno que podrás definir los parámetros que quieras y configurar cada variable/función como gustes.

```
myspineplot <- function(formula) {
    spineplot(formula)
}

p1 <- function(){myspineplot(improved ~ treatment)}
p2 <- function(){myspineplot(treatment ~ improved)}

p1()
p2()
```

#### Usar `pryr`

Como ya te lo comentó Rolando, hay una muy útil función `%<a-%`, lo que retorna  es lo que llaman un `<active binding>`, que produce que cada vez que se requiera la variable, ésta se reevalua dinámicamente, algo parecido a la solución funcional anterior.

```
library(pryr)
p1 %<a-% spineplot(improved ~ treatment)
p2 %<a-% spineplot(treatment ~ improved)

p1
p2
```

**Importante:**

No creo que sea tan sencillo reutilizar estos objetos con `grid.arrange()`, tal vez ya lo tienes claro y este comentario este de más, pero con gráficas base, la forma de ajustar varios `plots` es configurandolo mediante [`par()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html). Por ejemplo:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
spineplot(improved ~ treatment)
spineplot(treatment ~ improved)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por esta completa respuesta. Me permite seguir aprendiendo. En efecto, me he dado cuenta que pierdo funcionalidad al utilizar estos objetos con grid.arrange(). Sí puedo, sin embargo, utilizar par(). Me pregunto si es muy difícil generar una leyenda común para los colores que has utilizado en el último multigráfico. Algo sencillo, en la base del gráfico, que represente cada color para los niveles alto, medio y bajo.

Comment: @pyring, en teoría es posible, no te lo puedo mostrar en mi respuesta por que justamente los spineplots tienen leyendas distintas, pero es relativamente fácil usando `layout()`, esto puede ser un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389967/common-legend-for-multiple-plots-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `%a<-%` del paquete `pryr` para guardar el conjunto de código de cada gráfica

```
library(pryr)
plot.1%<a-%{tbl<-spineplot(y ~ as.factor(x),
                 col=paleta, 
                 xlab = "x", 
                 ylab ="y", 
                 yaxlabels = "", 
                 main= "Round 1") 

for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2)}

plot.1
```